# Перекрываются скрипты

Tags: bootstrap, javascript

Есть

```
<label id="block2tarif1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#shag3" class='tarifoff1'onclick="show_alert(4)" >Лэйбл</label>
```

data-toggle отвечает за плавное появление элемента, а oneclick обрабатывает переменные. Проблема в том, что при 3-м нажатии на <label> срабатывает только data-toggle. Как сделать, чтобы этого не происходило?

Comment: @Defiler, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Повесьте обработчик нажатия в теле скрипта, как-то так:

```
$('.tarifoff1').click(function(e){/* тут ваш обработчик*/})
```

Comment: Т.е. в скрипт, где data=toggle, перенести функцию show_alert?

Comment: У вас там ещё параметр - 4, я не знаю, что он значит, но наверняка его можно занести в атрибут вроде такого:

    <label id="block2tarif1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#shag3" class='tarifoff1' data-alert="4" >Лэйбл</label>